# Which is the best way to say "this is my life and my family's life we're talking about."

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, pronouns

A) "This is me and my family's life we're talking about."

B) "This is my and my family's life we're talking about."

C) "This is mine and my family's life we're talking about."

I assume "my life and my family's life" would be unnecessarily long, wouldn't it? (although it adds some emphasis and weight to the statement )

Comment: B) is arguably correct, but awkward and open to criticism as being *thought* wrong, even if it isn't, and C) is simply wrong. There's nothing wrong with A). It's easily understood and not at all awkward. Of course, you could rephrase it altogether if you really wanted to: D) *This is the life of me and my family we're talking about.*

Comment: yeah that would be a much better phrasing. thanks

Comment: I like the way you said it in the title, with the emphasis.

Comment: You could also say, "It's my life and my family's that we're talking about".